# How to convert marathi data from pdf to excel in proper format

Tags: pdf

I am converting Marathi data from PDF to excel or word but it is not getting proper format.
I have copied some data from PDF and pasted in word document but it was not getting proper format.
 e.g. प्रविण सुधाकर शिरवाडकर this line is in PDF
 but when i copied and pasted in word it has been getting
 -प्रववर् सुधाकर शिरवाडकर
what should i do for this?
anyone please help me.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be problems in the way PDF stores unicode devnagri text. Try this alternative route: convert your PDF to an image. Can use an online tool or downloaded, or if on linux use this command in terminal:

```
for f in *.pdf; do convert -density 200 "$f" "${f}_200dpi.jpg"; done
```

change the density from 200 to other as per need. Each page from your document should be converted into an image file. For a windows tool, try https://www.pdfill.com/pdf_tools_free.html

Then, go to  http://www.i2ocr.com/free-online-hindi-ocr, upload the image and convert. That uses OCR (optical character recognition).

Answer (score 0):

check the font in your PDF and try making it available to the word document.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have perticular fonts which are used in PDF

In Adobe Reader  --  -- File menu > Properties > Fonts tab gives you a list of all fonts used in the document.

Comment: open the document in adobe Reader, right click on it , then click on Document Properties, click on fonts tab. It will show all the fonts used on that document.